# how do I read ONLY the first value from the consol window? , the value is an int

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that will check the first character of a phone no. and depending on what the no, starts with, the code will do some actions. Im not sure how to make the if statement only check the first value.

```
Console.WriteLine("enter your phone n0.");
        int UserChoiceF = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n");
       // StreamReader sr = UserChoiceF.OpenText();
        //int FirstChar = sr.Read();


        if (UserChoiceF == 4 || UserChoiceF ==5 || UserChoiceF == 3)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < bred; i++)
            {

                Console.SetCursorPosition(startx + i, hoj / 2);
                Console.Write(top);

            }}`enter code here`
```

Comment: There is no point in converting a phone number to an integer. You're never going to use it for arithmetic.  Just leave it as a string.  Then you can check `UserChoiceF[0]`.

Comment: Omg, you totally right, thanks for making that clear. 

I changed the code to this:     string UserChoiceF = Console.ReadLine();

                            if (UserChoiceF[0] ==4 || UserChoiceF[0] == 5 || UserChoiceF[0] == 6)
                            {
                                ram.tegn2();

                            }

Comment: Should I put "" around the numbers? cause now its dosent seem to compare or read the input value

Comment: Yes.  If you want to check the first number, you'll check `UserChoiceF[0] = '4'`.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it as a string:

```
    Console.WriteLine("enter your phone n0.");
    string UserChoiceF = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then there are various ways you can check how it starts:

```
    if (UserChoiceF[0] == '4' || UserChoiceF[0] == '5' ...

    if (UserChoiceF.StartsWith("4") || UserChoiceF.StartsWith("5") ...

    if("456".Contains(UserChoiceF[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out. I finally achieved my goal!